# Excel 2019 VBA Set row height only for rows with data

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2019
Windows 10

Using VBA I Need to set the row height to 18 but for only rows that have data

I have tried variations on the following

```
Sub UsedRowsHeight1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Titles Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).RowHeight = 18

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub UsedRowsHeight2()

    Rows().AutoFit
    Rows.End(xlUp).RowHeight = 18

End Sub
```

None do what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "rows that have data"? Are there empty rows in the used range? Do you want meaning the used range, in fact? Your actual code set the row height **for the last row (in column A:A)**...

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Sub UsedRowsHeight1()

    lr = Sheets("Titles Data").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Titles Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Sheets("Titles Data").Range("1:" & lr).RowHeight = 18

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next way:

If you need/want setting the row height for **all used range**, even if there are empty rows in between, please, use the next code:

```
Sub RowHeightForRowsForUsedRange()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).RowHeight = 18
End Sub
```

To hide only rows of the used range **having at least a cell with data on the row**, please use the next version. In order to be fast, it uses a `Union` range to collect first cell of the rows having data and increase their height at once, at the code end:

```
Sub RowHeightForNotEmptyRowsInUsedRange()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngUR As Range, rngH As Range, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   
   Set rngUR = sh.UsedRange
   For i = 1 To rngUR.rows.count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngUR.rows(i)) > 0 Then
            addToRange rngH, rngUR.cells(i, 1)
        End If
   Next i
   If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.RowHeight = 18
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first version causes VBA Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @user2303407 This can be handled (a normal error when `SpecialCells` does not return a range (for formulas of constants). But didn't you see my comment where I asked for clarifications related to what you try accomplishing? What do you really want hiding?

Comment: I do not want anything to be hidden. I thought my post was clear but if not, on a worksett I wanted to set the height of any row that has data. This is to make it more readable.

Comment: @user2303407 "hiding" came from another question I was commenting... Of course, increasing the row height. As I asked clarifications for more issues, I still do not understand what you really want. **If you need increasing the height for all the used range, even for empty rows, please use the second code version, as stated**. If not, please better define what "any row that has data" means. If there is data on the first row, no any data in the second and data exists on the third one, **should the code increase the height in the second one**, too? Are there formulas returning an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

this uses special cells to select rows that have data (so if you have empty rows between filled rows they will not be affected)

```vb
Sub ChangeRowHeight()
    Dim rngConst As Range
    Set rngConst = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Dim rngForm As Range
    Set rngForm = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)
    Union(rngConst, rngForm).RowHeight = 18
End Sub
```

Comment: your code causes a VBA 400 error